# Single Line of text converts & to %26

Tags: 2010, soap

I am using Soap Architecture to enter a value into a sharepoint column(single line of text).

All Special characters get added. Only when & is added it gets converted to %26 in the list.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

`&` gets encoded to `%26` becuase it is a reserved keyword that is used in query strings. This is intended behavior and it is the client (your code's) responsibility to decode it back. In JavaScript you can use the below

```
decodeURIComponent('%26')
```

Comment: where do you want me to decode it... Its a Post Soap request with value within URL like PostBody- ...{"column":"C&O"}

Comment: Can you update the code you are using to create a new item?

Comment: yes it can be modified. & is entered correctly in multiline text column but gets converted to %26 for single line of text.